# Flex Bison: Building C Compiler - Line number in error message

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

When I try to print my line number in my yyerror function, I get an error. I'm working on OSX.

(line number in compiler.l)

```
%{

#include "compiler.tab.h"
int lineNumber = 1;

%}
%%

int { return INT; }
float { return FLOAT; }
void { return VOID; }
do { return DO; }
while { return WHILE; }
if { return IF; }
return { return RETURN; }
else { return ELSE; }
\/\/(.)* { return COMMENT; }
\/\*(.)*\*\/ { return COMMENT; }
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]* { return IDENT; }
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ { sscanf(yytext, "%lf", &yylval.reell); return FVAL; }
[0-9]+ { yylval.integer = atoi(yytext); return IVAL; }
\( { return OPA; }
\) { return CPA; }
\{ { return OB; }
\} { return CP; }
\; { return SEMICOLON; }
\, { return COMMA; }
\! { return NOT; }
\-\- { return DECREMENT; }
\+\+ { return INCREMENT; }
\<\< { return LSHIFT; }
\=\= { return EQUALS; }
\<\= { return LTOE; }
\>\= { return GTOE; }
\&\& { return AND; }
\|\| { return OR; }
\= { return ASSIGNMENT; }
\< { return LT; }
\> { return GT; }
\/ { return DIVIDE; }
\* { return MULTIPLY; }
\+ { return PLUS; }
\- { return MINUS; }
[ ]+ { return BLNK; }
[\n]* { ++lineNumber; return NL; }

%%
```

compiler.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "compiler.h"

extern int lineNumber;

int main (void)
{
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}

void yyerror(char * str)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s, Line %d\n", str, lineNumber);
}
```

I get the following error message:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_lineNumber", referenced
>   from:
>         _yyerror in compiler.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

This is the command (shell file) I use to compile:

```
#!/bin/bash

flex  compiler.l
bison -d compiler.y

gcc -g -c compiler.tab.c -o compiler_y.o
gcc -g -Wall -std=c99 -c lex.yy.c
gcc -g -c compiler.tab.c -o compiler_y.o

gcc -g -Wall -std=c99 -c compiler.c
gcc -g -o compiler compiler.o compiler_y.o lex.yy.o -lm -lfl
```

Comment: Please be careful when tagging.  Flex is used for the Apache/Adobe UI Framework.  Gnu-flex is used for the lexical analyzer.

Comment: Where in the `.l` file did you put that line? It seems like you're not defining it as an external symbol (or, if you are, you're not including the compiled lexer in your executable).

Comment: @rici I put the whole code of the compiler.l. Hope this helps. Thanks all for your help.

Comment: How do you compile/link? You may compile lex output as C++, then it will have different signature. You may forget to link your parser module altogether.

Comment: I wonder if `\/\*(.)*\*\/` and `\/\/(.)*` are correct. Can `(.)*` match `*/`? Also, what about string literals like `"// blah //"` and `"/* blah */"`? Will this parser be able to distinguish comments from string contents?

Comment: Your flex file looks ok, so I agree with @ValeriAtamaniouk that you've probably got an error in your compile/link commands.

Comment: I've added my compile commands. @Alexey Frunze thanks, but I am currently working on this and this is for university. It is not finished yet, the next step we need to do is the line number in error message for better debugging.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `%option yylineno` in your flex source and then the variable `int yylineno` will give the line-number of your current token. Beware not to use `yylineno` from the grammar (bison/yacc) as the tokenizer in general is ahead of the parser. If you want to use line numbers in the parser, typically the line numbers are attached to the tokens, so the parser has access through the tokens.

The error message is likely caused by not linking in `compiler.tab.o`, obtained from `compiler.l` by running `flex` on it and then passing it through the C-compiler.